# How could I implement a serial communication protocol in a object-oriented form?

Tags: delphi, oop, communication

I’m working on with an embedded device that is connected to PC using RS232.

I need to do a software to communicate with this embedded device.

I program in Delphi. I never used to use object-oriented in the past. But I'm trying to change this.

I am not able to think in an object oriented manner to solve this problem.

I have this protocol:

```
<STX><STX><COMMAND>[<DATA><DATA>...]<CHKSUM><ETX>
```

where:

```
<STX> is the Start of TeXt (0x55);
<COMMAND> can be 0x01 for read, 0x02 for write, etc;
<DATA> is any value;
<CHKSUM> is the checksum;
<ETX> is the End of TeXt (0x04).
```

The software computer will send a command via serial, and the device will answer, using the same protocol.

For example:

```
Reset command
PC sends     : <STX><STX><0x09><0x00><CHKSUM><ETX>
Device answer: <STX><STX><0x09><0x00><CHKSUM><ETX>

Get Version
PC sends     : <STX><STX><0x00><0x02><CHKSUM><ETX>
Device answer: <STX><STX><0x00><0x00><VER_L><VER_H><CHKSUM><ETX>
```

I have to send a file stream to the device.

I'd like to obtain suggestions and/or examples of the best way to implement this in an object oriented manner. I'd like to be able to do unit-test too.

Thanks

Comment: Serial comms needs a state-machine to work well. There are plenty of ways to do object oriented state-machines.

Answer (score 5):

You should look at other serial send/receive communication models, such as HTTP.  In .NET, the HTTPWebRequest object is where you gather together all the pieces of info to be sent across the wire - including command (HTTP METHOD: GET, PUT, POST, etc) and byte stream.  The HTTPWebRequest object (and the HTTP stack) internally deals with the "paperwork" of calculating checksums of the data, chunking large data into smaller packets, etc.  All your code has to do is construct the request object, set the command, assign a stream of data to the request object's property, and send.

Another reason why you should look at existing communication object models like .NET HTTP is that serial comms are generally asynchronous from the perspective of your host CPU.  A lot of CPU time can pass by while transmitting the characters of the request on the serial port, and while waiting for the response.  Use an async model for your request/response so that you don't block the calling thread and potentially freeze your UI.

To continue the .NET HTTP example, HTTPWebRequest has a GetResponse method which sends the request and will block the calling thread until a response is received.  HTTPWebRequest also has a BeginGetResponse()/EndGetResponse() pair so that you can send the request and provide a callback to be executed when the response arrives at some later time.

Even if your immediate design is ok with a thread-blocking synchronous call model, you should at least investigate asynchronous coding patterns and consider implementing your object as such.  You can always call an asynchronous method in a thread-blocking synchronous way, but it's much more difficult to call a synchronous method in an asynchronous way.  Invest a little time now to give yourself more options down the road.

Comment: Those are huge protocols with a complexity level far beyond his needs. Keep it simple! The recommended way (by Microsoft) is to use threads for TX and RX with the overlap structure waiting for events. As soon there is nothing to do, the threads will sleep and free up the process.

Comment: I didn't suggest that he use HTTP to implement serial comms. He was asking for ideas on how to arrange an object model. He should use an async call object model, and HTTP is one widely available model to look at for ideas on what to build in your own async object model.  The API's overlapped I/O structure doesn't provide any guidance for how to build a convenient and robust object model.  It's a low level detail that an object model would probably make use of, but the object model probably needs to do more than just call the API.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I guess there are as many solutions as there are programmers. Without knowing more about your system I would probably go with this approach:

Create a base command class, lets say; TBaseCommand. Define your common interface at this level, like Send(), Receive(), Run() etc...

Only fill in code for functions common for all commands, such as sending, receiving etc...

Functions that will differ in execution are made virtual to be defined in the next layer.
From this derive a new class for each command and fill in the command specific code, such as Run().

Having a Run() will easily allow you to simulate your commands on screen by overriding the Run() function.

,  and  are your transport protocol and should be applied and stripped of by your communication interface (separate protocol class?). Your protocol class can also handle checksum errors and try to resend etc.. If it can't be solved, signal error.

This was only a few things on top of my head with your limited description...

Answer (score 2):

Sort of hard to answer but from the small amount of info I have, here's how I'd do it:

Either you class that knows how to serialize themself or you use the visitor pattern for serializing. This has the advantage of decoupling your data from the serialization and let you implement other serialization mechanism more easily.

So I'd have a Data class, a Command class which contains a collection(choose your preferred container) of Data. The Command class would likely handle the checksum calculation through a public method. I would also have a communication class to encapsulate the Command and begin and end the communication. Then I'd have a class responsible for interfacing with the serial port which would have a Send method that would take a reference on the communication class.

From the available info, that's what I can come up with design-wise.

As for unit test, with a good design, you should be able to unit test almost everything. Remember to use stubs, you don't want to hit that serial port during testing so make a fake serial communication class that writes in a string for example and compare the outputted string to the expected value specification wise.